# While using Shopify-Laravel Osiset PER-USER mode not working?

Tags: laravel, authentication, shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to use PER-USER mode in osiset,for that i have changed the configuration to
`'api_grant_mode' => env('SHOPIFY_API_GRANT_MODE', 'PERUSER')` but while authenticating it returns unable to verify signature,why this happens?

Comment: Have you set `SHOPIFY_API_GRANT_MODE ="PERUSER"` in `.env` file?

Comment: no in config/shopify-app.php

Comment: `env('SOMETHING', 'FALLBACK_IF_SOMETHING_NOT_FOUND')` will check env file. So check if you have something set there. Also, after changing config files, you should issue `php artisan config:clear` command.

Comment: yes its working now